# How many spells does a Magician get to learn?

Tags: shadow-of-the-demon-lord

From the manual, I cannot understand how many spells a level 1 Magician gets. It says:

> "You make four choices, discovering one tradition or learning one
> spell for each. Cantrip Whenever you discover a tradition, you learn
> an extra rank 0 spell from that tradition."

Also:

> "When you discover a tradition, you automatically learn one of the rank
> 0 spells from that tradition."
>
> Whenever you discover a tradition, you learn an extra rank 0 spell from that tradition.

*"or learning one spell for each"* seems to imply you learn one spell for each tradition (learned?). However, it seems to generally be interpreted as just learning one spell. (Perhaps I am meant to read *"discovering one tradition, or learning one spell, for each choice"*?

Under the latter interpretation, I can 4 times choose to learn either 2 level 0 spells or 1 level 1 spell (of a tradition already learned).

Moreover, Occult Philosophy adds:

> Whenever you are eligible to learn a new
> spell, you can learn a second new spell in place of one
> you have previously learned. In effect, you forget one
> spell and learn a different one. When you exchange
> one spell for another, the rank of the spell you want to
> learn must be equal to or lower than your Power score.

Thus it seems that I should always learn new traditions since that makes me eligible to learn a new spell (level 0), and that makes me eligible to exchange a spell for a level X spell where x is equal to or lower than my Power score.

Thus I can for example repeat the following 4 times:
Learn a new tradition. Learn a level 0 spell. Learn another level 0 spell, exchange my previous one for a level 1 spell.

This leaves me with 4 level 0 spells and 4 level 1 spells, which is far more than when I would naively have taken level 1 spells, not using the more favorable "exchange".

This does not make too much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You start with between six and nine spells, including *sense magic*

You may be working from an old version of the core rules. The Magic and Cantrip traits for a level 1 Magician in the current revision of *Shadow of the Demon Lord* are on page 55, and say:

> **Magic** You discover one tradition. Then, make three choices. For each choice, you either discover another tradition or learn a spell from a tradition you have discovered.
>
> **Cantrip** Whenever you discover a tradition, you learn an extra rank 0 spell from that tradition.

Note the change in the Magic trait; that you must discover at least one tradition is now explicit. The other choices you make are between “discovering a tradition” and “learning a spell”, which clearly indicates these are two different things. That’ll be important later. In a similar vein, Cantrip specifies that you learn another rank 0 spell when discovering a tradition - a modification to the discovery rules, but not a standard opportunity to “learn a spell”, though it uses some similar language.

The rules for discovering a tradition appear on page 111, at the start of **Chapter 7: Magic**:

> **Discovering Traditions**
>
> To cast the spells associated with a tradition, you must **discover** the tradition. [...] Discovery indicates you have learned the fundamental techniques required to cast spells from the tradition, represented by one of its rank 0 spells.

Note that this doesn’t specifically use the language that you have “learned a spell” - rather you’ve learned the basic techniques of the tradition, which is represented by a rank 0 spell. Again, discovering a tradition is different to learning a spell, even if it does come with a rank 0 spell (or two for Magicians).

Magicians also get the trait **Sense Magic**, also on page 55:

> **Sense Magic** You learn the *sense magic* spell described here.

As a level 1 Novice Magician, you discover one tradition, for which you would know one rank 0 spell. Then because of the Cantrip trait you would learn a second rank 0 spell from that same tradition. You could then choose to discover three other traditions, gaining two rank 0 spells from each, or discover fewer other traditions, and also learn one or more new spells of rank 1 or 0 from the traditions you’ve discovered. Plus you get *sense magic* for free.

To spell it out (sorry) explicitly, you start with *sense magic* plus one of these combinations of spells:

- Eight rank 0 spells, two from each of four different traditions; or
- Six rank 0 spells and one additional rank 1 or 0 spell, from three different traditions; or
- Four rank 0 spells and two additional rank 1 or 0 spells, from two different traditions; or
- Two rank 0 spells and three additional rank 1 or 0 spells, all from a single tradition.

So: **at level 1, no more than three of your spells are rank 1.**

### You can’t exchange a spell you’ve just learned

But what about exchanging spells? Well, you can’t do that yet.

The rule for exchanging spells has also been updated in the core rules and matches (if not word for word) the one you quote from *Occult Philosophy*.

From page 111 of *Shadow of the Demon Lord* (my emphasis):

> **Exchanging Spells**
>
> Whenever you *learn a new spell*, you can exchange *a spell you have previously learned* for another spell of the same or lower rank.

And here’s the *Occult Philosophy* version, from page 7 (emphasis mine):

> **Exchanging Spells**
>
> [...] Whenever you are eligible to *learn a new spell*, you can learn a second new spell in place of *one you have previously learned*.

The key here is that the spells you can replace must be ones you have *previously learned* - i.e. some time before the new spell you are learning now. At the time you discover a tradition, you are newly learning your two rank 0 spells; and in any case, “discovering a tradition” is a distinct activity from “learning a spell”. The rules for it explicitly say you gain rank 0 spells, not a spell of a rank equal to your Power or lower, which is the general rule for learning a spell.

What about the choices at level 1? Well, you have no spells at all until you make your choices - you don’t have *any* “previously learned spells”. It might seem the choices are sequential, since the traditions you discover influence your choice of spells if you learn a spell with one or more of those choices. But everything you get at gaining a level effectively happens at once in game terms, though narratively you might explain it differently.

So at level 1, you can’t exchange any spells, since you haven’t previously learned any. And you cannot swap out one of your brand new free rank 0 spells from discovering a tradition at any level, since discovering a tradition is not the same as learning a spell.

You *can* swap out those rank 0 spells at later levels when you learn new spells, but be careful: if you replace all of your lower rank spells, you will only be able to cast a handful of spells a day, as higher ranked spells get fewer castings.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it is clearly not the intent but is anything making it clear that you can't swap out spells from your first "choice" when you learn spells "later" with your second choice. Would that count as "previously"?

Comment: @Kvothe I’ve been thinking about how to add this to my answer, but I think the fact that there’s a choice between “discover a tradition” and “learn a spell” indicates those are two different things. While you do get two free rank 0 spells when you discover a tradition, this is not always referred to as “learning” those spells, and I read it as meant to be treated differently.

Comment: I agree that it was probably not intended you immediately swap spells gained at level 1. On the level of rules lawyering I don't think your distinction holds up though. It explicitly says you "learn a new spell" see for example the Cantrip text you quote in your answer.

Comment: @Kvothe - it does; but it also says you specifically learn a rank 0 spell. For me at least, that is distinct from “the opportunity to learn a spell”, which follows standard “learn a spell” rules. From an intent point of view, if Cantrip was meant to let you learn an additional spell of any legal rank, I think it would say so. You could interpret it to let you refrain a spell from a previous level when you learn the second rank 0 spell, but again I don’t think that’s the intent.